# minimum requirement for a mono project to execute in different platforms

Tags: c#, mono

I'm developing a desktop application with C# (.net 2.0 framework), I will compile it with Mono develop in windows and will change the GUI to GTK#,

What is the minimum requirement of frameworks must present in different platforms to execute this application. 
 In windows it is .Net 2.0 , 
what it is in linux , ubuntu centos etc..., 
what it is in mac..?

Also it will be helpful to know the default version of framework existing in each platform.
Please send some helpful url or references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono usually supports the same runtime version for all plattforms; that means if you target and develop against the .NET35 profile on say OS X, your Application will also run on Linux (and of course windows) with mono on that profile. Same holds true for the .NET 2.0 and 4.0 profiles. The .NET 2.0 is the one most complete and stable, but to my experience the .NET35 and .NET4 profiles are very usable, too; lot of .NET35 libraries compiled for Windows will just run out of the box on Linux and OS X if you use mono.

**A word of warning:** I've worked with Gtk (not restricted to Gtk#) on OS X and must say, you should avoid it. The gtk-quartz branch is not nearly as stable as its linux counterpart. There are several known issues that will reproducibly crash your application (i.e. there are issues with Drag'n'Drop), and some pieces are missing completely. Only using the X11 backend with gtk on OSX will yield satisfying results, but provide a very poor integration into the OS and user experience.

You might want to consider developing different GUI frontends for each OS: Gtk# on Linux, WPF on Windows, Cocoa via [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac), or take a look at the in-development [Xwt](https://github.com/mono/xwt) framework.